# my application is not showing up when i click on my branch.io deeplink from twitter

Tags: android, deep-linking, branch.io

after sharing a deep-linked link (branch.io) in twitter and on click it, my application is not in the type of options given to open it. Only browsers are there. is this the behavior of twitter or any mistakes on my side?

My manifest file:

```
<receiver
            android:name="com.indiatoday.util.TwitterIntegrationHelper$MyResultReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetcomposer.UPLOAD_SUCCESS" />
                <action android:name="com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetcomposer.UPLOAD_FAILURE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service
            android:name=".util.DownloadService"
            android:enabled="true"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="xxx" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey"
            android:value="key_test_xxx" />
```

Comment: share manifest file

Comment: added manifest in edit

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add intent filter to your activity as below also make sure you configure branch url host as per  android:host mentioned in app

```
     <intent-filter>
            <data
                android:host="abc.app.link"
                android:scheme="https" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Apk, Please clarify me how to use the data tag in manifest. Do i need to register two data tags for https scheme and app:appname:// scheme with the same host name?

Comment: A2N you need to know about deep linking android please search for it and get idea about same

Comment: Let me check it out thoroughly again. but, i guess twitter is using chrome in build to load urls that are shared.

Answer (score 0):

In order for your app to show up in the `Open in` options menu, you need to setup your App to support App Links.

You can read about, App links on the Android official documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html).

In order to setup App links with Branch,

1. On your Branch dashboard, you need to check `Enable App Links` in the Link Settings and add your SHA256 certificate.
2. In your Android Manifest, add the Intent filter to the Activity where you want to support the App link redirection

   ```
    <!-- Branch App Links (optional) -->
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="example.app.link" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="example-alternate.app.link" />
   </intent-filter>
   ```

Replace `example.app.link` with the link domain from your Branch Dashboard.

Comment: Hi. I have already added 2 intent filters. 1 for host="open" with my defined scheme in branch dashboard and another like your code. Eventhough, its still not showing up in twitter.

Comment: @A2N Are you able to see your app in the list when you click on the link outside of twitter?

Comment: Yes. in facebook, gmail and whatsapp its showing in the listing of options.